# How Play base64 encoded mp3 in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio

After many search I could play mp3 with this code in Phonegap:

```
if (device.platform == 'Android') {
src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
}

var mediaRes = new Media(src,
function onSuccess() {
// release the media resource once finished playing
mediaRes.release();
},
function onError(e){
console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
});
mediaRes.play();
```

But I need to play a base64 encoded mp3 not a mp3 file

can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're still looking for it, you just have to add `"data:audio/mpeg;base64,"+your_B64_string`

Comment: Is this really an answer to this question?

Comment: @Goyuso no it's a comment and yes it does solve OP's problem

Comment: Finally, I have resolve my problem natively