# How to play a base64 encoded mp3 from a string in a Cordova Chrome App on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I'm getting a Content Security Policy directive violation when trying to play an mp3 from a base64 encoded string.

Context: I'm developing a Chrome App that I convert to an Android App using Apache Cordova. When running the Chrome App on my computer everything works like a charm, but when running the App under Android I see the following error in the console:

```
Refused to load media from 'data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAA…AAAAD/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src *".
```

The code is pretty simple:

```
var sound = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…AAD/';
new Audio(sound).play();
```

As far as I can see I can not loosen the restriction "media-src *". I added this to my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src *">
```

And these (just for testing) to my config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
```

But no success...

I also tried what was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804080/how-to-use-audio-in-a-mobile-chrome-app).

```
function onSuccess() {                                  
  console.log('success', arguments);                    
}                                                       
function onError() {                                    
  console.log('error', arguments);                      
}                                                       
function onStatus() {                                   
  console.log('status', arguments);                     
}                                                       
var player = new Media(sound, onSuccess, onError, onStatus);
console.log('Using cca Media');                         
player.play()
```

Output:

```
Using cca Media
status { 0: 1 }
error { 0: { code: 1 } }
```

So this does not seem to be suitable for playing music from a base64 string because I see this when checking logcat:

```
I/MediaPlayerService(28744): [setDataSource] setDataSource(/storage/sdcard0/data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAAA…bR+0Ne
D/MediaPlayerFactory(28744): getPlayerType(): using url, check for DRM protected midi.
D/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(28744): checkDcf ----> path [/storage/sdcard0/data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAAA…t5A2r/
V/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(28744): checkExistence ----> [/storage/sdcard0/data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAAA…Vt5A2r
E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(28744): checkExistence failed, reason [File name too long]
E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(28744): checkDcf: file does not exist.
D/MediaPlayerService(28744): player type = 4
E/DrmMtkUtil(28744): [ERROR]isDcf() : failed to dup fd, reason [File name too long]
I/MediaPlayerService(28744): [setDataSource] setDataSource(/storage/sdcard0/data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAAAA…txIbR+0Ne
I/MediaPlayerService(28744): [prepareAsync] [45] prepareAsync
D/NuPlayer(28744): kWhatPrepare, source type = 0
E/        (28744): Failed to open file '/storage/sdcard0/data:audio/mp3;base64,//tQxAAAAA…5A2r/
```

It assumes the source is a filename. I also did not find anything in the documentation to force it to interpret it as a data URI.

In fact [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358459/how-play-base64-encoded-mp3-in-phonegap) was my hottest lead, but the resolution is not really clear to me since it looks he is (eventually) successfully doing it just the way I have unsuccessfully tried it...

So, what is the proper way to play audio from a base64 encoded string in Android?

Comment: The important lines looks like `E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(28744): checkExistence failed, reason [File name too long]` and `E/DrmMtkUtil(28744): [ERROR]isDcf() : failed to dup fd, reason [File name too long]`, look into converting _Base64_ to _Blob_, generating an _Object URL_ from the _Blob_ (this URL will be much shorter because it's just a hash for the file on disc), playing the file at the _Object URL_

Comment: That could work, but something is still wrong: `[ERROR]isDcf() : failed to dup fd, reason [No such file or directory]` and more specifically `Failed to open file '/storage/sdcard0/blob:file%3A///4cdb5ef6-db62-4bd1-bb2b-0eafd8303a62'. (No such file or directory) ` The URL I'm generating is `blob:file%3A///4cdb5ef6-db62-4bd1-bb2b-0eafd8303a62`. I feel like the prefixing (done by the Media function somewhere in the process) with `/storage/sdcard0/` is causing problems here, or should it be like that?

Comment: The linked question uses mimetype "audio/mpeg" for the data URL (not "audio/mp3"), backed up by this question on [Which mime type should I use for mp3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688588/which-mime-type-should-i-use-for-mp3).

Comment: That sounded promising, but also with mimetype `audio/mpeg` it still gives me the CSP violation: `Refused to load media from 'data:audio/mpeg;base64,//tQxAAA…AAAAD/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src *".`

Comment: `Failed to open file '/storage/sdcard0/blob:file%3A///4cdb5ef`... means that the URI is being treated as a path or is not on the node correctly (should start with the `blob:` protocol

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem. The documentation describes the field as "src: A URI containing the audio content."[1]. So I would expect it to be able to deal with `data:` and `blob:` URIs. [1]: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/index.html#media

Comment: * But for some reason it prepends `/storage/sdcard0` to the path.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding `data:` to media src? `*` does not cover all values like you may think.

Comment: Ahh okay, I now tried `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src 'self' * blob: data:">`. Which is correctly interpreted when running it as a Chrome App on my Desktop Computer. But when deploying to my phone it still says it violates the directive `"media-src *"`. So on my phone it is following a different directive.